# Are the odds of a cryptographically secure random number generator generating the same uuid small enough that you do not need to check for uniqueness?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, uuid

I'm using [this](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) with a length of 20 for uuid. Is it common practice to not check if the uuid generated has not been used already if it's used for a persistent unique value?

Or is it best practice to verify it's not already being used by some part of your application if it's essential to retain uniqueness.

Comment: The short answer is "yes". 20 bytes = 160 bits. How many records do you think you'll accumulate over the life-time of your project? Punch it in here: http://davidjohnstone.net/pages/hash-collision-probability The odds are so slow its not worth the CPU cycles (nevermind the developer hours)

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the probability of a collision using [this formula from Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack):

[image: n(p;H) ≈ √{2H ln[1/(1-p)]}]

where *n*(*p*; *H*) is the smallest number of samples you have to choose in order to find a collision with a probability of at least *p*, given *H* possible outputs with equal probability.

The same article also provides Python source code that you can use to calculate this value:

```python
from math import log1p, sqrt

def birthday(probability_exponent, bits):
    probability = 10. ** probability_exponent
    outputs     =  2. ** bits
    return sqrt(2. * outputs * -log1p(-probability))
```

So if you're generating UUIDs with 20 bytes (160 bits) of random data, how sure can you be that there won't be any collisions? Let's suppose you want there to be a probability of less than one in a quintillion (10<sup>–18</sup>) that a collision will occur:

```
>>> birthday(-18,160)
1709679290002018.5
```

This means that after generating about 1.7 quadrillion UUIDs with 20 bytes of random data each, there is only a one in 1 a quintillion chance that two of these UUIDs will be the same.

Basically, 20 bytes is perfectly adequate.

Answer (score 1):

crypto.RandomBytes is safe enough for most applications. If you want it to by completely secure, use a length of 16. Once there is a length of 16 there will likely never be a collision in the nearest century. And it is definitely not a good idea to check an entire database for any duplicates, because the odds are so low that the performance debuff outweighs the security.

Comment: I think 16 bytes (128 bits) is enough actually. Even with a trillion records, the odds are about 0.00000000000014432899%.